# After inserting record's into SFMC Data extension, I see some unwanted texts are inserted along with normal text

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, sql, automationstudio, email-studio

I have inserted record's into DE. But after insertion, I can see some unwanted texts are also insered into the fields.

***Expected:***

question (field)

How are you  I&I ? (Records)

***uploaded records:***

Question (fields)

How are you I&amp ? (Records)

How to avoid those characters (I&amp)

Comment: Can you provide more information on how you insert these records? Manually? File Import? Smart Capture? Api?

Comment: These records are inserted into DE using sql queries.. Data transferred from one DE to another DE

Comment: I would assume SQL moves them 1-1, without encoding HTML entities (which is what is happening here). I would check your source DE as well, and additionally the very source of the data, which seems to be a website which encodes HTML entities prior to submitting these to SFMC.

Comment: In source DE everything looks good

Comment: Can you share your query?

Comment: Select t1. email, t2. Question from test1 t1 inner join test2 t2 on t1. Email=t2.email